# Confusion about d3.js selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My HTML looks like this:

```
<svg height="680" width="650">

<g transform="translate(20,20)">
    <g class="zoom">
        <g class="edgePaths"></g>
        <g class="edgeLabels"></g>
        <g class="nodes">
            <g class="node enter" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(216.1875,16.5)"></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I want to select the "node enter" class, so I did this:

```
node = d3.selectAll("svg").selectAll("g").selectAll("node enter")
```

It doesn't return the correct elements. Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you're having is that selectors for classes use a dot (`'.'`) prefix (see @Oleg's answer).

An additional issue is that you don't need to `select` the parents of the element you are trying to select beforehand. Instead, you can `select` that element directly, e.g.

```
d3.select("g.node.enter")
```

Note that since you're selecting a single element, you can just use `d3.select`. In general if  multiple elements match the selection criteria, it will just return the first, but in this case you know there's only one such match.

Answer (score 3):

Your last selector is attempting to find `<node enter></node enter>` elements.

The selector for classes uses a dot prefix, e.g. `".node"`.

In your example you could use:

```
nodes = d3.selectAll(".node.enter");
```

You can read more about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).